# How can I stack wildcards to target specific files?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, wildcards, ln

I want to target all files called `fooxxxbarxxx`. The common thing among all those files is that it contains `foo` and `bar`.

I've tried to use `*foo*bar*` and `*foo**bar*` but it doesn't work.

Specifically, I'm trying to create soft links to those files, and the rest of the code already works for more straightforward executions (looks into all subfolders of `path`):

`shopt -s globstar`

`ln -s /path/**/*foo*bar* .`

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you using, what shell and what is the result? What doesn't work?

Comment: What is the output of `echo /path/**/*foo*bar*`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open or list all files whose name matches two patterns in Bash](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/287070)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash` shell you need to use `extglob` option for this OR type shell expansions.

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
```

and then do the globbing as

```
ln -s /path/**/@(*foo*bar*|*bar*foo*)
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
find /path -name '.*' -prune -o -name '*foo*' -name '*bar*' -exec sh -c '
  ln -s "$@" .' sh {} +
```